# What kind of 'bottoms of mountains' are these in Jonah 2:7?

Tags: yonah-jonah-book-of

> Jonah 2
>   7 I was going down to the bottoms of the mountains,
>   to a land whose bars would close me in forever;
>   but you brought me up alive from the pit,
>   Adonai, my God! `Complete Jewish Bible`

The 'bottoms'( ''cuttings'') of mountains which happen to be in the pit makes the verse obscure as the pit is said to 'bottomless,' and a place well known to be the abode of the dead.
In addition he says that he saw the bars of the earth 'forever,' yet he was in the 'belly' all the while he was submerged and for ONLY 3 days, up until he was vomitted onto the land.

So what are these 'bottoms of mountains' which Jonah saw in the pit, because in my opinion, no detail in scriptures in redundant.

Comment: It should be noted that this book you reference to (CJB) is not a Jewish source despite the name.

Comment: @Renato Grun Give me an answer according to the correct version.

Answer (score 4):

[Yonah 2:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16184#v=7&showrashi=true)

> To the bottom of the mountains I descended, the earth-its bars are
>   closed on me forever; but You brought up my life from Gehinnom, O
>   Lord, my God.

Rashi says

**To the bottoms of the mountains I descended**: To the end of the measure of the mountains fixed to the deep, I descended. And I said...

When he was swallowed by the fish it brought him to the uttermost depths. That is, the base of the mountains that rise up from the sea bed. He felt that he was being punished to the greatest extent possible and lacked all hope of redemption. However, Hashem would hear his prayers and understand his teshuvah and redeem him from the depths. Even in the depths of despair he still has hope and faith in Hashem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do you explain mention of the 'PIT', which is a synonymous with Sheol? Besides when he was in the fish, he never never looked around at anything until he was vomited up by the fish, let alone that one can distinguish any feature at the depths you are suggesting.  The language says he 'saw' these thing including the bars of the earth about 'FOREVER'. It's clear enough that the Most High delivered him.

Comment: @TedO if you wanted to know about the pit, you should've included that in your question post. Feel free now to ask a new question.

Comment: @ msh210 I expected the one who should answer my question to consider all  what the verse says. It's not the pit I am asking about, but the 'bottoms' of mountains who happen to be in that pit, a place well known to be the abode of the dead, in addition that  he saw the bars of the earth 'forever,' yet he was in the 'belly' all the while he was submerged and for ONLY 3 days up until he was vomitted onto the land. That's why sabbahillel didnt address what asked.

Comment: @TedO, then, it seems that your question was not clear enough. Edit to specify this or ask a new question as msh210 recommended you before.

Comment: @ Renato Grun   my bad, I will do.

Answer (score 0):

The posuk from [Yonah reads](http://kodesh.mikranet.org.il/i/tm/t1702.htm):

> I went down to the **bottoms of the mountains**, the earth has closed me
>   forever with its bars, yet You brought up my life from the pit O
>   Lord, my G-d.

[Yalkut Shimoni 550](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_9758_173.pdf) says that this is (a vision in which he saw) the Bais Hamikdosh since its construction stands upon the mountains.

**EDIT**:

The pit is nothing but the *grave* that Hashem rescued him from, which happens to be the fish itself, (see 2:3). Therefore, the posuk says that when he was in the belly of the fish (the pit) he had a vision of the Temple (the bottom of the mountains) as the Yalkut says.